# Detection of weak signal by satellites

Tags: electrical-engineering, power-electronics, rf-electronics

An animal's blood pressure and/or body movements can be used to generate a few mW of electrical energy. Can an RF transmitter which radiates 1 mW be detected by receivers (without any parabolic reflectors) on satellites? The receiver has to only detect the signal and power level, no data transfer is required. This could be used to locate the animal.

Comment: So, what is the question?

Comment: @SolarMike I decoded it! It was hard, but I did. His question is, could be animals localized by satellites using an 1mW RF transmitter, embedded into them.

Comment: @peterh can I embed rf transmitters in my students so I know where they are :)